# Split a Signal Based on Frequency for High-Power Applications

Tags: frequency, shunt

Normally when one wants to do analysis on a signal based on certain frequency ranges the obvious choice is to filter for those individual ranges and then conduct the analysis based on the result.

Instead of filtering out certain frequencies, I would like to shunt the power in a given frequency range to a different circuit for processing (possibly to be summed up with other processed frequency ranges later).

I expect the solution is to present high impedance to the given frequency range in one leg of the circuit so that it gets shunted to another branch.

I doubt this is a new idea but my google searches haven't born any fruit.  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This is the same as filtering. The filter presents a low impedance to the frequencies it passes and a high impedance to the frequencies it blocks.

For low loss filters consider T and \$\pi\$ filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diplexer is the circuit you are looking for, usually something you see in RF applications.

Comment: Or a crossover network if you are working at audio frequencies...

Comment: I am interested in low frequencies: DC to 1kHz.  Is there something similar

Comment: Passive crossover as Deam mentioned, but the magnetics become progressively more annoying as the 3dB point drops.